# Combine Two Sql Statement

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create sql statement. It will be find a random user id in database and also from VOTES table, visitor(user id=10) have not give vote yet to a user which determined by randomly.

```
$userid = 10
//1-Find a user randomly 
$query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$randid = $query["id"];

//2-Visitor have not give vote to the user which we determine. This sql result will be empty
("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE userid = '{$userid}' AND receiver = '{$randid}'")
```

I have to combine these 2 sql statement. I need this because the website will open a user profile which a visitor have not give vote to that user.
Thanks

I used these codes before but these codes mostly show a profile which visitor gave vote so i need to add check from votes table

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$randid = $query["id"];
header("location:index.php?id=$randid");
```

[example link](http://example.com)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I need a Find user which i havent give a vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I don't understand what you're trying to do from your description.

But to combine the two queries, the simplest method would be to include the first in the second as a subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM votes
       WHERE userid = '{$userid}'
             AND receiver = (SELECT id
                                    FROM users
                                    ORDER BY rand()
                                    LIMIT 1);
```

---

Edit:

Your comment makes me believe you might be searching for something like:

```
SELECT *
       FROM users u
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM votes v
                                WHERE v.receiver = u.id
                                      AND v.userid = '{$userid}')
       ORDER BY rand()
       LIMIT 1;
```

It gets a random record from `users`, where no record in `votes` exists, that has this user from `users` as `receiver` and the `userid` equal to the "visitor" or what ever that `10` is.

That is, if I understand correctly, `votes.receiver` is the user for whom another one casts a vote and `votes.userid` is the one who casts the vote.

Comment: i need a statement that find a random user from USERS table and visitor have not use a vote yet to that user. maybe i cant do this with sql manybe i need a loop or smthng

Comment: you are great :) i spent my all night for solving this. Thank you for your help. I havent see any statement which include "v.", I need to work about that

Comment: @can: Welcome! On the "v", that's called an alias. Those can be given to tables and columns in queries. Feed "SQL alias" in a search engine to learn more.